# Which size auto siphon to empty a 5 or 6.5 gallon carboy?

Tags: racking, siphon, equipment

I got an auto siphon as a gift recently.  Unfortunately, it only reaches about half-way down into the carboy.  All the brew supply sites and the fermtech site, itself, aren't exactly clear about the exact dimensions of the various auto siphons and about whether or not they'll reach the bottom of a 6.5 gallon carboy.  Which one should I buy?

Edit: I think I may have been given the mini model.  Mine is 24" long when fully extended, but 13.5" long when collapsed.  Here is a picture of it in a 5 gallon carboy.  You can see it isn't getting the job done:

[image]

I'm guessing the standard model is 24" long when collapsed.

Comment: This picture makes me sad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is *not* the mini auto siphon.  I've confirmed I received the mini one, and yeah, it doesn't reach the bottom of a 5 or 6.5 gallon carboy.

Comment: That sucks.  If you order a new one, I recommend the 3/8ths" diameter one (standard).  The larger 1/2" diameter one has to fast a flow rate and pulls air sometimes and doesn't work as well as the standard 3/8ths.  Good luck

Comment: Thanks.  I did order the 3/8" one because I figured the 1/2" one would prove more difficult in getting to the corner of a tilted carboy due to less wiggle room in the neck of the carboy.  Your point about sucking air is a good one, too.